# Cann't reach pypi.org

Tags: 20.04, 22.04, docker, pip, wireguard

Context:
I have 2 machine:

1. VPN Server (Ubuntu 20.04)
2. Host machine (Ubuntu 22.04)
3. Both of them connected throught WireGuard VPN and Host transfer all his traffic throught VPN Server.
4. On Host machine I have docker (23.0.1)
5. SSH work fine (I could connect to both machine by SSH)

When I run container inside docker and run pip install ****, I get an error that pypi.org is **HttpConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Read timed out**

I can not understand reason.

What I find:

1. When WireGuard is switch off, everything works fine
2. If WireGuard is switch on:

- pip doesn't work at all
- If I run Ubuntu container *apt-get* work fine
- If I Run Debian container *apt-get* doesn't work
- If I Run Debian container switch of WG run *apt-get update* and then switch on WG, then *apt-get update* work fine.

What I have done:

- add DNS = 8.8.8.8 to the VPN server config, Host machine config
- on both machine in UFW port/upd allow to both directions

I will glad to any advise. And explanation what is happened

=======

Continue searching: I found that curl https://pypi.org in Ubuntu container doesn't work until I switch of WireGuard BUT curl http://pypi.org work fine at any time.

Answer (score 0):

Problem was in MTU size.
I have increase MTU size in WireGuard server config and WireGuard client config

```
[Interface]
...
MTU=1500
...
```

Source of answer is here https://github.com/cmulk/wireguard-docker#other-notes. Author writes that there is a problem when HTTP, Pint work fine and HTTPS and SSL don't. And then he gives link to solution.